# How to get file as Buffer object from URL?

Tags: node.js

I've seen this question [Get image as buffer from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421522/get-image-as-buffer-from-url) already.

But I don't want to use the `request` library, anyone knows how to do this with only Node.js(v16) build-in modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import https from 'https'

async function getBufferFromUrl(url: string): Promise<Buffer> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    https.get(url, (response) => {
      const body: Buffer[] = []
      response
        .on('data', (chunk: Buffer) => {
          body.push(chunk)
        })
        .on('end', () => {
          resolve(Buffer.concat(body))
        })
    })
  })
}
```